# Visualize large amount of data using PyQtGraph

Tags: python, plot, hdf5, pyqtgraph

I need to plot a large amount of data using PyQtGraph. By large I mean 256 vectors of around 100k points, all of that on the same plot. I managed to generate the plot using pyqtgraph, however the features like scrolling/zooming/etc are very very slow. I was wondering how I can make these features smooth again?

For info, the data is static and saved in a hdf5 file. I don't need to manipulate or make computation with the data, just need to plot it so that the user can smoothly vizualise it.